# Returning a new value

Tags: c#

I have write a function but this function still returns me the old string in stead of the new one. I don't know how to return a new string when you did something with the old one

By example:

```
public string TestCode(string testString)
{

// Here something happens with the testString


//return testString; <-- i am returning still the same how can i return the new string //where something is happened with in the function above

}
```

Comment: I believe you should consider posting actual code. It's not clear what "happens with the test string".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> // Here something happens with the testString

Make sure what ever you are doing with the string, you are assigning it back to `testString` like.

```
testString = testString.Replace("A","B");
```

since string are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

I assume you are calling the function like:

```
string somestring = "ABC";
somestring = TestCode(somestring);
```

Comment: my bad. Its so immutable that I'm able to treat it like a value type. (Without thinking about it, oops).

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable (i.e. cant be changed). You have to do like this

```
      myString = TestCode(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure you assign the new string value to a variable (or the parameter `testString`). For example, a very common mistake here is:

```
testString.Replace("a", ""); // remove the "a"s
```

This should be:

```
return testString.Replace("a", ""); // remove the "a"s
```

or

```
testString = testString.Replace("a", ""); // remove the "a"s
...
return testString;
```

The point is: `string` is immutable: `Replace` etc do not change the old string: they create a new one that you need to store somewhere.